# How to use Opencore AMR in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, amr, opencore

iOS 4.3 no longer supports playing AMR Audio Files which is horrible and completely kills my app. Some people have suggested using [Opencore-amr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/) but I'm at a loss in terms of how to compile the library and integrate it into my iPhone application.

I'm looking for any tips or help I can get in terms of how to compile the library, include/link the library in my app, and sample source code for using this library to play AMR files in an iPhone app.

Comment: Why can't you just convert to a different audio format?

Comment: Because Android phones can only record audio with AMR encoder and I need to be able to send Android audio to iPhone phones and vice versa.

Comment: So, why not record the audio in AMR on Android, and then have a process to convert it on a background thread?